# Why is a -dev package not added to Yocto image packagelist

Tags: yocto, bitbake, openembedded

I've added a `-dev` package to my `IMAGE_INSTALL` variable in my target BitBake recipe:

```
IMAGE_INSTALL = " \
    ...
    catkin \
    catkin-dev \
    ...
    "
```

After `bitbake <target>`, this package is in my package feed:

```
$ find . -name catkin-dev*
...
./tmp/deploy/deb/core2-64/catkin-dev_0.6.16-r0_amd64.deb
```

But it doesn't show up in my package list:
[image: catkin-depexp]

What's going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list on the left in DepExp should be called "recipes", not "packages".  My fault, sorry.  It's certainly confusing for people who don't look at the list and immediately see that it's a list of recipes instead of packages.

But the answer is catkin-dev doesn't appear in that list as it's a list of recipes (ie bitbake files, sort of) not built packages (ie catkin-dev).

Comment: Why is it your fault that it is named that way?

Comment: Because I wrote Dependency Explorer.